# Find the determinant of this matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

$k_1,k_2,...,k_n$ are non-negative integers.
Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with entries:
$a_{i,1} = t^{k_i}, a_{i,j+1} = \frac{da_{i,j}}{dt}$ where $a_{i,j}$ is the element of $i$-th row and $j$-th column.

Prove that there exist $C$ and $r$ such that
$\det(M) = Ct^r$

I was able to reduce it to:

$\det(M) = t^{(k_1+...+k_n) - {n(n-1)\over 2}}$
$\cdot \det\begin{pmatrix}
 1& k_{1} & k_{1}(k_{1}-1)  & ... & {k_1!\over (k_1-n+1)!}\\ 
 1& k_{2} & k_{2}(k_{2}-1) & \vdots & \vdots\\ 
 \vdots& \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots \\ 
 1& k_{n} & k_{3} & ... & {k_n!\over (k_n-n+1)!}
\end{pmatrix}$

I have  already determined $r$, the problem is to calculate  determinant of this thing, any tips ?

Comment: I'm not clear what the pattern ... means in your final matrix expression.  You said $k_i$ is a "non negativ(e)", but unless it is an integer it's unclear what $k_i !$ should mean.

Comment: @hardmath Ops, they are integers yes. I forgot it, thank you :)

Comment: @hardmath ... means... How to explain, it is to show that matrix go on without writing every terms. Actually the three points should be vertical in some parts, but i don't know how to write it

Comment: Thank you @PM2Ring, now it is nice

Comment: @hardmath The terms are permutation numbers, sometimes written as $$^nP_r=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$

Comment: There are also diagonal dots, `$\ddots$`, $$\ddots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle  C=\pm \prod_{1\le i<j\le n} (k_j-k_i)$ .

I hope you know the **Vandermonde Determinant** and how to compute it.
If $k_i=k_j$ for some $i\neq j$  or $max\{k_1,k_2,...,k_n\}\le n-2$ then $det(M)=0$.

Comment: You might link to an account of the [determinant of a Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), and clarify how the matrix in the Question is related to a Vandermonde matrix, e.g. by elementary column operations.  The plus-or-minus sign in your expression is not needed (it is + with subscripts as shown).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that taking $C$ to be the above determinant and $r$ to be exponent of $t$ in your expression solves your problem.